# How to hide multiple columns using jx:if

Tags: java, jxls

i have been using jxls tags to write data from java to excel.

but for a certain condition failure i would like to hide multiple adjacent columns. But placing all of them between one jx:if tag displays only one column when my condition pass.

```
|column A | jx:if(condition) | column C | column D | column E | close of jx:if
```

when my condition is passed, i am able to see only `column A` and `Column C`.

Note: i have been hiding the columns in excel once `jx:if` tag is implemented, since they are coloured.. If not hided this appears as coloured cell with no text when my condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you can try if you use Jxls 1.x (with Jxls-2 it is a different story)

1. Via transformer as explained in the documentation [Column Hiding](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/1.x/reference/columnhiding.html)
2. Using direct [access to POI objects](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/1.x/reference/poiaccess.html) and use *sheet* object to set it column hidden using POI sheet method *sheet.setColumnHidden(int columnIndex, boolean hidden)*
3. Use plain POI API after the template is processed with Jxls
4. Using Excel macros